# Xcode Storyboard Changing Preview

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, device, preview

I am using Xcode 13.3 and I cannot change my devices preview like I desire. I mean there are some different types of model but the model that I desire does not seem on the list. I attached the picture below.

[Storyboard Screen - Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCSBh.png)

On the previous XCode version, I used to do this easily, but not for XCode 13.3. I can change the simulator's view and add new devices but storyboard.

Is there any solution?

Comment: What device are you looking for? Many devices have the same screen size.

Comment: Looking for basically iPhone 13. I just wonder whether I can add the device or not.